# How do I send the crafted draft PayPal invoice using Python?

Tags: python, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am creating the desktop app that uses PayPal APIs to create draft invoice and send them to provided email addresses. I am following [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/invoicing/integrate/) and [this](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/v2/#invoices_create) official documentations of PayPal.

I am able to create the draft successfully. For some reasons, I am skipping the field `invoice_number` for now. Below is the code I am using to create the draft Invoice:

```
        merchant_email = self.emailInput.text()
        item_name = self.itemNameInput.text()
        currency_code = self.currencyCombo.currentText()
        amount = self.amountInput.text()
        recipients = []

        invoice_data = {
            "detail": {
                "reference": "deal-ref",
                "invoice_date": "2023-09-03",
                "currency_code": currency_code,
                "note": self.noteToSellerInput.text(),
                "term": self.termsAndConditionsInput.text(),
                "memo": "This is a long contract",
                "payment_term": {
                    "term_type": "DUE_ON_DATE_SPECIFIED",
                    "due_date": "2023-09-05"
                }
            },
            "invoicer": {
                "name": {
                    "given_name": "David",
                    "surname": "Larusso"
                },
                "address": {
                    "address_line_1": "1234 First Street",
                    "address_line_2": "337673 Hillside Court",
                    "admin_area_2": "Anytown",
                    "admin_area_1": "CA",
                    "postal_code": "98765",
                    "country_code": "US"
                },
                "email_address": merchant_email,
                "phones": [
                    {
                        "country_code": "001",
                        "national_number": "4085551234",
                        "phone_type": "MOBILE"
                    }
                ],
                "website": "www.test.com",
                "tax_id": "ABcNkWSfb5ICTt73nD3QON1fnnpgNKBy-Jb5SeuGj185MNNw6g",
                "logo_url": "https://example.com/logo.PNG",
                "additional_notes": "2-4"
            },
            "primary_recipients": [
                {
                    "billing_info": {
                        "email_address": recipient_email
                    }
                }
            ],
            "items": [
                {
                    "name": item_name,
                    "description": "Elastic mat to practice yoga.",
                    "quantity": "1",
                    "unit_amount": {
                        "currency_code": currency_code,
                        "value": amount
                    },
                    "tax": {
                        "name": "Sales Tax",
                        "percent": "0"
                    },
                    "discount": {
                        "percent": "0"
                    },
                    "unit_of_measure": "QUANTITY"
                },
            ],
            "configuration": {
                "partial_payment": {
                    "allow_partial_payment": True,
                    "minimum_amount_due": {
                        "currency_code": currency_code,
                        "value": "0"
                    }
                },
                "allow_tip": True,
                "tax_calculated_after_discount": True,
                "tax_inclusive": False,
            },
            "amount": {
                "breakdown": {
                    "custom": {
                        "label": "Packing Charges",
                        "amount": {
                            "currency_code": currency_code,
                            "value": "0"
                        }
                    },
                    "shipping": {
                        "amount": {
                            "currency_code": currency_code,
                            "value": "0"
                        },
                        "tax": {
                            "name": "Sales Tax",
                            "percent": "0"
                        }
                    },
                    "discount": {
                        "invoice_discount": {
                            "percent": "0"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        response = requests.post('https://api-m.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices', headers=headers, json=invoice_data)

        return response.json()
```

and this works fine, and returns the 201 response in API Calls in the PayPal Developer dashboard.

After creating the draft, the next step is to send the invoice. Following is the code which I am using to send the invoice:

```
        headers = {
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {self.access_token}',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'PayPal-Request-Id': 'b1d1f06c7246c',
        }

        invoice_id = invoice["id"]

        send_data = {
            "send_to_invoicer": True
        }
        send_invoice_url = f'https://api-m.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices/{invoice_id}/send'

        response = requests.post(send_invoice_url, headers=headers, json=send_data)

        if response.status_code == 202:
            self.responseDisplay.append(f"Invoice {invoice_id} sent successfully!")
        else:
            self.responseDisplay.append(f"Failed to send invoice {invoice_id}: {response.text}")
```

But this returns 422 status with the following error message:

```
Failed to send invoice INV2-NESE-CXZ3-V698-VHDU:
{
    "name": "UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY",
    "message": "The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.",
    "debug_id": "221545f2e6532",
    "details": [
        {
            "field": "invoiceId",
            "value": "INV2-NESE-CXZ3-V698-VHDU",
            "location": "path",
            "issue": "REQUEST_REJECTED",
            "description": "Could not process the request. Please contact customer service team for any queries."
        }
    ],
    "links": [
        {
            "href": "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/invoicing/#errors",
            "method": "GET"
        }
    ]
}
```

Please note that I am using the PayPal Live APIs, not the PayPal Sandbox APIs.

I tried to look up this issue in the Google search and even tried to look at it ChatGPT, but I could not find any solution. I even double checked that if I am using correct Python code and things and I believe that I am using correct doe. Please anybody tell me what's wrong I am doing.